# How to get the roles of multiple users in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

If I'm having 2 tables with n:n relationship, users and roles.
How can I get all roles for all users in laravel.

example:

| John | Jack |
| --- | --- |
| role1 | role1 |
| role2 | role3 |

Comment: do you have a pivot table? are you using Eloquent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't forget to use with() to reduce N+1 problem. do simple foreach and fetch the name.

```
// Get all users with assigned role
$users = \App\User::query()->with('roles')->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name . '<br/>';
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        echo $role->name . '<br/>';
    }
}

// Get all user of a specific role
$users = \App\User::query()->whereHas('roles', function ($query) {
    $query->where('name', 'isAdmin');
})->get();
foreach ($users as $user) {
    echo $user->name . '<br/>';
    foreach ($user->roles as $role) {
        echo $role->name . '<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @SaabeerDev , I'm getting the roles, but as assigned in the pivot table. How can I get the specific role?

Comment: I have made some edit's where fixed the loop for role and also answered your second question.

Answer (score 0):

By foreach

```
foreach($users as $user) {
    $user->roles;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Reda , I'm getting the roles, but as assigned in the pivot table. How can I get the specific role?

Comment: $user->roles,  Now u have the list of roles assigned to that specific user, do what u want to do with it.

Answer (score 0):

Use spatie packages https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-permission/v5/introduction
This help you to create role and permissions.